Transparency is allowed in C# WPF?
I'm creating a C# WPF program, which I will have to broadcast live on twitch with OBS studio, I have inserted this code into the program to enable transparency, but I noticed that with transparency enabled OBS does not show anything, did I do something wrong?
inside the application there are several buttons, and a stackpanel that contains several UserControls if inserted by the user
On OBS I used Simple Window Capture and Game Capture with transparency enabled, but it doesn't work
<Window /** OMISSIS **/
Title="Counter"
Height="320" Width="700"
MaxHeight="320" MaxWidth="700"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
WindowStyle="None">

That obs shows the program with transparency enabled so as not to show the background

Could you use the chroma key/green screen feature of OBS and set your window background to a solid colour? https://restream.io/learn/obs-studio/how-to-use-obs-green-screen/ This may provide a quick workaround letting you focus on your task inside of OBS.

@AnthonyG. It works! thank you very much
